# Code to output a number of columns based on search criteria

Tags: excel, vba

My sister has a worksheet at work with the first five columns containing patient's information, and then columns have the heading of each date for the whole month. She needs non-technical operators to be able to filter the information to show only records which have appointments for that day, plus two days either side.

Currently, she manually filters the column of the date she wants to remove the "blanks" for that date, which shows only the patients who have appointments for that day, hides the other columns to show just that date and then prints the information out for the date.

What is the best way to automate this process?

I've played with several different methods like copying it over to a new sheet or autohiding data but I'm having trouble displaying a list of patients with no blank in the field for that specific day (i.e. - they have an appointment!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... is it possible to upload a copy of the worksheet? Sorry for the confusion, tricky to explain. Ideally, I would have a button which initiated a popup to select a date, which then outputs the correct information for the user to keep it very simple. Thanks

Comment: I've uploaded it here: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/aa316f620334b911dbbcea3eea9b94b720131221214714/d410dacbffd7fbb2a73c57961dc1c0b520131221214714/f87269

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will be a proper answer, but might give you some ideas – and won’t fit in a comment:

1. I'd suggest Columns 2,3,4,5, & 6 are stored elsewhere and merely referenced for current purposes. This is partly because I'm guessing there are a lot more patients (ie details) than required for any one month. So an index would be useful (say just a few characters rather than maybe typing around 20-30 at present - and the risk of errors), but `Name & DOB` would serve. Use this in your existing sheet (which I have called `Month`) to retrieve the appropriate details for ColumnsB:F for the relevant month. By the looks of it the likes of “Tany M/W CAF Meeting” may best be entered manually.
2. I'd suggest top aligning all cells (may help with matching one column to another, given your data).
3. In a new sheet put labels such as `Name & DOB`, `B/D`, `C & V details`, `Contact Details`, `delivery details`, `M/W`, `OVERDUE`, `overdue`, `TODAY`, `PENDING`, `pending` in Row2. (I suggest no highlighting for the first six so as not to clash with red, amber, pale blue, green, dark green for the five days.)
4. I say Row 2 so that in Row1 there is room for a date. This could be constructed with a (rather horrible) formula such as:

   `=VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(DATE(O2,O1,I1),3),DofWeek,2,0)&", "&TEXT(DATE(O2,O1,I1),"dd mmmm yyyy")`

where manual entry is in `I1` (just the day of the month), the month in say `O1` (just the month number) and the year in say `O2`. The intent it that only those three cells are ever adjusted on the ‘extra’ sheet (and two of the three only rarely). This allows, for safety, protecting the sheet after only unlocking just the three cells. `DofWeek` is a named range to convert `0` to `Monday` etc. I think it is important that the relevant date of the selection is very evident.
5.  In `G4` put:

```
=INDEX(Month!$G$2:$AK$6,MATCH($A4,Month!$A$2:$A$6,0),$I$1-2)
```

and copy across to `K4`. Then copy all five cells down as far as required.
6.  Optionally, in order to be able to hide details that appear on sheet `Month` that are not relevant for the 5-day view, you might add:

```
=COUNTIF(G4:K4,"<>0")
```

in `L4` and copy that down to suit.
7.  Row3 I deliberately left blank so that the body can be filtered without the little arrows obscuring other information (ie select Row3 and down to suit before applying a filter). Filtering for ColumnL for not `-` (I chose an Accounting format for the main body of cells – so that results are ‘discrete’ dashes rather than `0`s).

Snags with this include:

1. The need to change the Month number when appropriate. This could be driven from the computer’s clock but I’d suggest best not to (eg for flexibility). Note that a month such as 13 would work but might be confusing if the Year cell has not been updated.
2. Perhaps the main problem is uncertainty of how far ‘down’ is sufficient for `as far as required`. However many cells are preloaded with formulae there is always a risk that one month that won’t be enough. But this could be countered with a check to compare the number of entries on the two sheets.
3. Based on one month at a time, will not give a 5-day view at the start and end of each month (but will show warning that the 5-day period is not fully populated with the relevant data). This could be addressed by duplicating the last two days of each month as though the start of the next.
4. Formatting is not transferred with INDEX/MATCH.

I have assumed that at the end of each month sheet `Month` will be archived before being wiped clean of data, ready for the following month. All data entry is in sheet `Month`, though hopefully the data in B:F can be collected from elsewhere via the index field.

Comment: +1 for including analysis